# How to label and measure size of blobs?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am learning image analysis with Python, I am just a beginner. I was able to write a code (I am sharing it below) to detect the blobs (nanoparticles) in this nanoparticle image:

[image: Nanoparticle image]

I can detect that there are 10 nanoparticles using `cv2.connectedComponents`, but now I need to:

1. Label each nanoparticle with a number to generate a final image.
2. Calculate the number of pixels that composes each nanoparticle so that I can determine their size.

I tried to research around, but couldn't find anything that works for me. Anyone that is willing help me? If you can propose a code it would be great, if you could also explain it it, it would be super!

```
import numpy as np
    import cv2
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    img = cv2.imread('Izzie -  - 0002.tif')

    #show figure using matplotlib
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 1) # Figure 1 has subplots 2 raws, 2 columns, and this is plot 1
    plt.gca().set_title('Original')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)) # , cmap='gray'

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 2) # Figure 1 has subplots 2 raw, 2 columns, and this is plot 2
    plt.gca().set_title('Gray')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)) # , cmap='gray'


# In global thresholding (normal methods), we used an arbitrary chosen value as a threshold
    # In contrast, Otsu's method
    # avoids having to choose a value and determines it automatically.
    #The method returns two outputs. The first is the threshold that was used and the secon
    # output is the thresholded image.

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

print('Ret = ', ret) # Applies an arbitrary threshold of 128

plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
    plt.gca().set_title('Threshold')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # MORPHOLOGICAL TRANSFORMATION
    # noise removal using morphological trasnformations
    # For more info see: https://opencv-python
tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html

    # Set up the kernel - structuring element
    kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8) # 3x3 array of 1s of datatype 8-bytes

    # Remove noise using Opening (erosion followed by dilation)
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, iterations = 4)
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
    plt.gca().set_title('Noise rem')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(opening, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))


    # sure background area
    # dilation operation
    sure_bg = cv2.dilate(opening,kernel,iterations=3)

    plt.figure(2)
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
    plt.gca().set_title('Dilated img')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(sure_bg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))



    # Apply a distance transformation to transform the image into a gradient of B&W pixels and detect possible connected objects
    dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.DIST_L2,5)

    plt.figure(2)
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 3) 
    plt.gca().set_title('Dist_transform')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(dist_transform, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))



    # Apply a threshold to go back to binary B&W image
    ret, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform, 0.7 * dist_transform.max(),255,0)
    print('Ret treshold: ', ret)

    plt.figure(2)
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 4) 
    plt.gca().set_title('Threshold')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(sure_fg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))


    # Finding unknown region
    sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg) # creates an 8-bit unsigned matrix

    plt.figure(3)
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1) 
    plt.gca().set_title('Sure_fg')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(sure_fg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))


    unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg,sure_fg)

    plt.figure(3)
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2) 
    plt.gca().set_title('Unknown')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(unknown, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))


    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

    # Marker labelling
    # Connected components counts all black objects in the image. For explaination see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMIrQdX4BkE
    # It gives 2 objects in return, the number of objects and a picture with labelled objects.

n_objects, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)

    plt.figure(4)
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1) 
    plt.gca().set_title('markers')
    plt.imshow(markers) 


    # Add one to all labels so that sure background is not 0, but 1
    markers = markers+1

    # Now, mark the region of unknown with zero
    markers[unknown==255] = 0


    markers = cv2.watershed(img, markers)
    img[markers == 8] = [255, 0, 0] # Overlay red circles (-1 val) to img. 2, 3, 4 are all the different objects detected in the image

    plt.figure(4)
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    plt.gca().set_title('markers')
    plt.imshow(img)



    print('Number of particles detected: ', n_objects-2)


    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your particles are (almost) black, don't use Otsu's threshold, but a fixed to mask the (almost) black pixels. On the inverse binarized image, you can then apply morphological closing (to get the whole particles) and opening (to get rid of the background noise), see [`cv2.morphologyEx`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f). Afterwards, you find all contours to get the particles and the scale, see [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0). We determine the bounding rectangles of all contours for placing some labels on the particles in the input image, as well as to calculate the horizontal and vertical diameters of the particles by dividing the width/height of the particles' bounding boxes by the width of the scale's bounding box.

In my code, I omitted several things, including the Matplotlib outputs. (While writing, I just noticed, there's a lot more code from you; I didn't see the scroll bar... I haven't seen that, and didn't incorporated that code, too.)

```py
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import io                  # Only needed for web grabbing images, use cv2.imread for local images

# Read image from web; Attention: it's already RGB
img = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/J46nA.jpg')

# Convert to grayscale; Attention: Source is RGB from web grabbing
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# Use fixed threshold to mask black areas
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Morphological closing to get whole particles; opening to get rid of noise
img_mop = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7, 7)))
img_mop = cv2.morphologyEx(img_mop, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15, 15)))

# Find contours
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(img_mop, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Get bounding rectangles for the scale and the particles
thr_size = 2000
scale = [cv2.boundingRect(cnt) for cnt in cnts if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > thr_size]
particles = [cv2.boundingRect(cnt) for cnt in cnts if cv2.contourArea(cnt) < thr_size]

# Iterate all particles, add label and diameters to input image
for i, p in enumerate(particles):
    x = p[0]
    y = max(0, p[1]-10)
    d_h = p[2] / scale[0][2] * 500
    d_v = p[3] / scale[0][2] * 500
    cv2.putText(img, str(i), (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    print('Particle ' + str(i) + ' | Horizontal diameter: ' + '{:.2f}'.format(d_h) +
          ' nm, vertical diameter: ' +  '{:.2f}'.format(d_v) + ' nm')

cv2.imshow('img', cv2.resize(img, dsize=(0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
cv2.imshow('thresh', cv2.resize(thresh, dsize=(0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
cv2.imshow('img_mop',  cv2.resize(img_mop, dsize=(0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The `thresh` image with the fixed threshold:

[image: Thresholded image]

The `img_mop` image, after applying the morphological operation (Note: the scale is still there, so we can use it for size approximation):

[image: Morph image]

Finally, the input/output image `ìmg` with the corresponding labels (had to use JPG here due to image size restrictions):

[image: Final image]

Last, but not least, the `print` output:

```
Particle 0 | Horizontal diameter: 20.83 nm, vertical diameter: 23.03 nm
Particle 1 | Horizontal diameter: 20.83 nm, vertical diameter: 20.83 nm
Particle 2 | Horizontal diameter: 19.74 nm, vertical diameter: 17.54 nm
Particle 3 | Horizontal diameter: 23.03 nm, vertical diameter: 23.03 nm
Particle 4 | Horizontal diameter: 24.12 nm, vertical diameter: 24.12 nm
Particle 5 | Horizontal diameter: 21.93 nm, vertical diameter: 20.83 nm
Particle 6 | Horizontal diameter: 24.12 nm, vertical diameter: 23.03 nm
Particle 7 | Horizontal diameter: 21.93 nm, vertical diameter: 23.03 nm
Particle 8 | Horizontal diameter: 19.74 nm, vertical diameter: 21.93 nm
Particle 9 | Horizontal diameter: 19.74 nm, vertical diameter: 19.74 nm
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's amazing, thank you very much! Let me study your code now! :)