# Python: Measuring a particle size in an image from a given reference?

Tags: python, opencv, particles

I am a python beginner. I am working on counting and measuring particle sizes from 100s of images. I have an example image below. The particle with the arrow pointed towards it is 20 microns in height and width diameter. Is there a way to use that particle as a reference to count the number of and measure other similar particles? Is it through OpenCV?

Here's the reference image with the arrow pointed towards the reference particle that is 20 microns in height and width (can use the second particle below for testing purpose):
[image]

Here are other images that can be used to be tested:
[image]
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to label and measure size of blobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129982/how-to-label-and-measure-size-of-blobs)

Comment: See my edit for code

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the number of pixels for the height and width of your reference particle
2. Locate particles (because images are B&W it is straightforward).
3. Get the rectangle around these non-black area
4. Compare the width/height of the minimum bounding rectangle with the reference one.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import cv2
import numpy as np

WIDTH_REF = 50.0 # pixels
HEIGHT_REF = 50.0 # pixels

img = cv2.imread('example.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

res = np.array(img)

for c in contours:
    x, y, widthPixel, heightPixel = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    realWidth = widthPixel / WIDTH_REF * 20.0
    realHeight = heightPixel / HEIGHT_REF * 20.0
    cv2.rectangle(res,(x,y),(x+widthPixel,y+heightPixel), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(res, "{0:.1f}".format(realWidth) +" x " + "{0:.1f}".format(realHeight) + " microns", (x,y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    print(realWidth, " x ", realHeight)
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate this. I just have a few questions:

1) How did you get the number of pixels of the reference particle?
2) How can I get that last picture where there are rectangles drawn and size written next to each particle?

Thank you